# Vuejs and Vue.set(), update an Key/Value array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to figure out how the `this.$set (aka Vue.set)` api works when using it to update an multidimensional array.

Given:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    rows:[{"id": "4", "edit": "true" }, { "id": "5", "edit": "false" }] 

  },
....
```

How will I use `$this.set` to do something like this:

```
this.rows[0].edit = false
```

I know this doesn't work:

```
this.$set(this.rows2, 0, false)
```

What is the correct way to use $this.set for a KV pair array ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the `edit` properties in your `rows` objects are already set, you do not need to use `Vue.set` in this case. You can just set the property value and Vue will notice the change:

```
this.rows[0].edit = false;
```

Here's a simple example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      rows:[
        { "id": "4", "edit": true }, 
        { "id": "5", "edit": false }
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    editNext() {
      let index = this.rows.findIndex(r => r.edit);
      
      this.rows[index].edit = false;

      let next = ++index % this.rows.length;
      this.rows[next].edit = true;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(row, i) in rows" v-if="rows[i].edit">
    Editing Row ID {{ row.id }}
  </div>
  
  <button @click="editNext">Edit Next</button>
</div>
```

---

However, if the `edit` property of your row objects were not set initially (or if you just wanted to be safe), then you would need to use `Vue.set` in order to add the property and have it be reactive:

```
this.$set(this.rows[0], 'edit', false);
```

Here's an example of that case:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      rows:[
        { "id": "4", "edit": true }, 
        { "id": "5" }
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    editNext() {
      let i = this.rows.findIndex(r => r.edit);
      
      this.$set(this.rows[i], 'edit', false);
      
      let next = ++i % this.rows.length;
      this.$set(this.rows[next], 'edit', true);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="row in rows" v-if="row.edit">
    Editing Row ID {{ row.id }}
  </div>
  
  <button @click="editNext">Edit Next</button>
</div>
```

[Here's the documentation on Vue's Change Detection Caveats.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Comment: Thanks for the write up. I am not near my code to test your explanation but it makes sense.