# Vue.js - Values created in a method (on-click) not being displayed in a v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want the program to fetch some data `@click`and then display it in the `v-for` loop.

After I click the button, data shows up in the console, but I don't see anything being displayed on the page.

Is it because data is being created **after** the element has been rendered?
 How do I make Vue to re-render the loop to show the fetched data?

#### Codepen: https://codepen.io/x84733/pen/jKxQKo?editors=1010

```html
<v-btn @click="fetchData">
  fetch propeties 
</v-btn>

<h2>Properties:</h2>
<div v-for="item in properties">
  <div>{{item.title}}: {{item.value}}</div>
</div>

...  

data () {
  return {
    properties: {}
  }
},
methods: {
  fetchData () {
    var nameObj = {'title': 'name'}
    var sizeObj = {'title': 'size'}

    nameObj['value'] = 'file.txt'
    sizeObj['value'] = 12

    this.properties['name'] = nameObj
    this.properties['size'] = sizeObj

    console.log(this.properties)
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vuejs and Vue.set(), update an Key/Value array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809248/vuejs-and-vue-set-update-an-key-value-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In documentation of vuejs it is clearly mentioned that v-for is for arrays and not objects.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Your properties is an object which has name as size.

Make this change

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      properties: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData () {
      var nameObj = {'title': 'name'}
      var sizeObj = {'title': 'size'}
      
      nameObj['value'] = 'file.txt'
      sizeObj['value'] = 12
      
      this.properties.push(nameObj)
      this.properties.push(sizeObj)
      
      console.log(this.properties)
    }
  }
})
```

After this change your code will work fine

Comment: But if I create the object manually (before the loop is rendered) like that: `properties: {filename: {'title': 'filename': 'value': 'file.txt'}}` then it displays it. Why aren't the objects being displayed if a method creates it?

Comment: @Un1 because adding new properties to an object is not reactive (you would have to force the update). Read about reactive caveats here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: Ahh, got it, thank you very much for the code and the explanation!